Expand the string in R
I have a string
a <- c("C1", "C2", "C3)

and want to expand each element with ":A1" so that the whole sequence will be
"C1:A1" "C2:A1" "C3:A1"

Is there a way to concatenate these two together?

Try with paste0(a, ":A1")

paste0 is good here.  For more general replacements, learn "regular expressions" and gsub

That solves the problem! Thank you

Here is a benchmark for several base R options
a <- paste0("C", 1:1e5)

microbenchmark(
    paste0(a, ":A1"),
    sprintf("%s:A1", a),
    gsub("$", ":A1", a),
    sub("$", ":A1", a),
    check = "equal",
    unit = "relative"
)

which shows
Unit: relative
                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
    paste0(a, ":A1") 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
 sprintf("%s:A1", a) 1.244441 1.275613 1.194146 1.194490 1.132622 1.108782
 gsub("$", ":A1", a) 3.196967 3.043198 2.911267 2.895284 2.636584 2.442065
  sub("$", ":A1", a) 3.205933 3.069923 2.862013 2.893748 2.637672 2.006778
 neval
   100
   100
   100
   100

